# Why can questions closed by mods be reopened by users?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

A recent (?) feature change caused posts deleted by moderators not undeletable by regular users.

It seems like this is not the case for closed questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3577641/revisions

Was this just not considered or is it by-design?

Comment: I think it should be okay for users to be able to vote and undelete a mod-deleted question.  As long as they cannot undelete a locked question (for those extraordinarily bad questions).

Comment: What is it with the downvotes? I am not asking for a change either way, just an explanation as to why the behavior is (apparently) inconsistent –

Comment: Downvotes on meta...

Answer (score 13):

Moderators aren't perfect, and closes can be borderline. Sometimes, the mod might decide to close it, but it might be close enough that the community decides that the question is OK. Alternatively, the question might be edited to the point where it is now OK.

However, in some cases, moderators must overrule the court of public opinion for site quality reasons—in these rare instances, they can lock the post to prevent a reopening.

So why can't deletions be reversed? Because a deletion occurs when the post is so bad that there is no possible hope of recovery. Closed questions aren't (usually) deleted after a day because the OP might fix it; however, if a month has gone by and there's been no improvement, there's no point to it still being on the site.

But you say: well, if moderators aren't perfect, then can't they delete a question they shouldn't have been deleted? And the answer is, of course, yes. However, these cases are so rare that if they occur, you should raise the matter on Meta.

In other words, the code is based on the most common scenarios, and there are methods in place to handle the exceptions.

Comment: There are no good methods to handle bad deletions, you can only flag and take a hit.